# C# Calling helper functions from seperate classes in the same namespace without prefixing and with access to System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, class, oop, static, namespaces

*I'm pretty sure this is a newbie question, but I'm relatively new to C# and I haven't done so much with OOP in the past years (too much js). Just as a side note, I'm writing my projects in the .NET Framework 4.8 with asp.net web forms pages.*
Yesterday, I had a dream that I could put all my **generic helper functions** I normally just copy-paste into every new class I create into a seperate, dedicated helper class (within the same namespace) and then just call my functions **from anywhere** within that namespace as I would before (e.g. **without prefixing** with a class name, **no instantiation** etc.). Is this even possible? ^^
I've just read into interfaces, and I've already created a static class to see if that would work out - But while I don't have to instantiate that static class anymore, I still need to reference the helper class before I can use any of it's (also static) functions. Also, I'm not able to access the Request object or asp form elements from that static class, since I seemingly can't have it implement System.Web.UI.Page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do that with [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).  Depending on the method you might also want to make them [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: so in fact they are not "static helpers" but ther are extending Page functionallity, ergo, you should wrote common base class derived from Page ... you may also wrote extension method ... but using extension method inside class which it extends require using `this.`

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, I just read up on inheritance and I now have a common base class with Helper functions derived from System.Web.UI.Page, which my other classes then inherit. But I still can't access any asp.net elements on the pages themselves. Is there a way I can have my helper function access asp.net literals on the page itself without passing it as parameter to the function that needs it?

Comment: because they are exists only in you derived class ... also it really depends on context

Comment: one more off-topic comment: please, don't do this for yourself and world... just don't ... old ASP.NET aka WebForms are bad, so bad that every time you use it small kitten dies... use some newer framework like MVC in asp.net core

Comment: @Selvin I know, I would love to use .NET Core, blazor or some NodeJS framework I'd be a lot more familiar with. The thing is that I'm doing this for work, and they don't want to migrate to a newer version (project was launched in 2017).